# Get data from the backend in a different type variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to store data from the backend in a scores type variable.

I have the data from the backend stored as `scores1`:

```
(5) [Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4)]
0: (4) ["fake algorithm 1", "fake_scalar_1", "none", 0.679]
1: (4) ["csic's algorithm", "fake_time_series_1", "mean", 0.954]
2: (4) ["csic's algorithm", "step_length_right", "mean", 0.654]
3: (4) ["csic's algorithm", "step_length_left", "mean", 0.351]
4: (4) ["csic's algorithm", "step_time_right", "mean", 0.378]
```

That I would first like to put in my scores object.

Components.ts:

```js
  experiment1: scores[] = [];
  id1: number;
  id2: number;
  selectedExperiments: number[];
  scores1: any;
  
  ngOnInit() {
      this.selectedExperiments = this.experimentService.getTheId();
      console.log(this.selectedExperiments);
      this.id1 = this.selectedExperiments[0];
      this.id2 = this.selectedExperiments[1];
      this.compareService.getScore(this.id1)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.scores1 = response;
        for(var i = 0; i<(this.scores1.length-1);i++){
            this.experiment1[i].algorithm_name=this.scores1[i][0];
            this.experiment1[i].pi_name=this.scores1[i][1];
            this.experiment1[i].agg_type=this.scores1[i][2];
            this.experiment1[i].score=this.scores1[i][3];
            console.log(this.experiment1[i]);
        }
      }
    );
    this.compareService.getScore(this.id2)
    .subscribe(response => {
      this.scores2 = response;
      console.log(this.scores2)}
    );

  }
```

With the scores class:

```js
export class scores {
  public algorithm_name: string;
  public pi_name: string;
  public agg_type: string;
  public score: number;
}
```

This is the closest from the solution I got, now I have an error saying it doesn't know the algorithm name...
The `getScore()` method from the service works properly, using `console.log()` I get the data above.

Comment: Can you console.log(this.scores1) and add its value to the question

Comment: I get the first value I put above : (5) [Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4)]
0: (4) ["fake algorithm 1", "fake_scalar_1", "none", 0.679]
1: (4) ["csic's algorithm", "fake_time_series_1", "mean", 0.954]
2: (4) ["csic's algorithm", "step_length_right", "mean", 0.654]
3: (4) ["csic's algorithm", "step_length_left", "mean", 0.351]
4: (4) ["csic's algorithm", "step_time_right", "mean", 0.378]

Comment: ok but i think my answer should solve your problem as long as your this.scores1 has the correct response value and when accessing the this.scores1[i][blah] also gives you the correct values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your this.experiment1 needs to be populated before you can access values in via

this.experment1[i].whatevetPropertyName;

So you can:

```
for(var i = 0; i<(this.scores1.length-1);i++){
    const item = new scores();
    item.algorithm_name=this.scores1[i][0];
    item.pi_name=this.scores1[i][1];
    item.agg_type=this.scores1[i][2];
    item.score=this.scores1[i][3];
    this.experiment1.push(item);
}
```

Something like above. Create and populate a scores object in the loop and then push it to the array.